# indoor map returns false after the first run, setIndoorEnable

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2, google-indoor-maps

I am working with google map fragment. In onCreateView i call this function:

```
googlemap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
```

For the first run it is working but after this run others are wrong.

```
System.out.println(googlemap.isIndoorEnabled());
```

returns with false.

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to google docs about setIndoorEnabled(boolean enabled) :

> Sets whether indoor maps should be enabled. Currently, **indoor maps can only be shown on one map at a time and by default**, this is the first map added to your application. **To enable indoor maps on another map**, **you must first disable indoor maps on the original map**. If you try to enable indoor maps when it is enabled on another map, nothing will happen and this will return false. When Indoor is not enabled for a map, all methods related to indoor will return null, or false.